# How to combine two javascript FormData objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I need to combine two FormData objects and post them using XMLHttpRequest. One of the forms contains file input.

```
var formData = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem('form-ship'));
var poData = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem('po-form'));

// Combine them
var fData = $.extend(true, formData, poData);
```

It doesn't work when I use `$.extend` or if I use `serialize()` to combine the form that doesn't have file input. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: could you just set each of the two as a member of an array and then post the array?

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You <s>cannot</s> couldn't. [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) <s>is</s> was unfortunately not enumerable.

However, as you say only one of your forms does contain a file input. Then it should be possible to use [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) on the other and [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#append()) to the data manually:

```
var formData = new FormData(document.forms['form-ship']); // with the file input
var poData = jQuery(document.forms['po-form']).serializeArray();
for (var i=0; i<poData.length; i++)
    formData.append(poData[i].name, poData[i].value);
```

Comment: FormData.entries() - Returns an iterator allowing to go through all key/value pairs contained in this object.

Answer (score 26):

I did it this way:

```
let formData = new FormData($("#f_articulos")[0]);
let formDataPrecios = new FormData($("#f_listado_precios")[0]);
for (var pair of formDataPrecios.entries()) {
    formData.append(pair[0], pair[1]);
}
```

Comment: For anyone using this, the use of `entries` is not very well supported in IE and other browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=entries

Answer (score 0):

form_data_1 = new FormData(document.getElementById('form1'))
form_data_2 = new FormData(document.getElementById('form2'))

```
  for (const pair of form_data_2.entries()) {
    form_data_1.append(pair[0], pair[1]);
  }



  for (const pair of form_data_1.entries()) {
    console.log(`${pair[0]}, ${pair[1]}`);
  }
```