# How do I clone/extend a FormData object?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I have a set of POST endpoints where I need to send a collection of static parameters plus a few dynamic parameters specific to the request.

For every request, I am doing the following:

```
var staticParams = {...}, // some arbitrarily large object
    localParams = {...},
    formData = new FormData();

Object.keys(staticParams).forEach(function(key) {
  formData.append(key, staticParams[key]);
});

Object.keys(localData).forEach(function(key) {
  formData.append(key, localParams[key]);
});
```

It's not a huge tax, but it seems silly to repeat the first enumeration for *every request*. **How can I clone and extend my `FormData` object so that I don't have to build the whole thing every time?**

---

FWIW, I know [how to clone Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object); I believe `FormData` is unique in that the key/value pairs are not simply keys on the Object, so I am unclear on the correct way to clone it.

Comment: As far as I know, [such](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22409667/1048572) is not possible. But I don't think repeatedly appending your data for multiple requests doesn't have much of an impact.

Comment: @Bergi you've got a double-negative there; do you think this IS a problem or IS NOT a problem?

Comment: Ooops, I meant that it's NOT a problem - neither space- nor timewise.

Comment: var f = function() {this. formData = {'x':'y'};}
var newFormData = new f(). formData;, the new keyword should do the trick fast

Comment: @shayte it doesn't seem like you understand what `FormData` is? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Answer (score -2):

You could use the following function to be able to extend your objects.

```
if(Object.prototype.extend === undefined) {
    Object.prototype.extend = function(obj) {
        for (var i in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                this[i] = obj[i];
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Which adds the properties of the object 'obj' to the object the function is called on.

In your case, you could use it as follows:

```
formData.extend(staticParams);
formData.extend(localParams);
```

Comment: I know how to clone objects (and I certainly would _not_ do it by mucking with the Object prototype,) but `FormData` does not store its values directly as keys on the object.